# MySQL SELECT non empty value with unique invoice numbers

Tags: mysql

I have a table with all product sales, the table contain:

```
id
date
product
make
model
cost
taxes
invoice
```

Each product sold gets individually inserted to the table so if the customer purchased 3 different products with the same invoice number lets say ( 0009 ) then the table will look like this

```
product = example one
make = samsung
model = demo one
cost = 100
taxes = 19
invoice = 0009
```

second inserted product

```
product = example two
make = samsung
model = demo two
cost = 200
taxes = 38
invoice = 0009
```

Now the problem is:

I need to show all emited invoices during the day or week or month so I use the follow code:

```
$invoices = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `sales` WHERE `date` = '$today'");
```

The result I get is all products sold during this date. But I need to show only 1 product per invoice ( because I only need to display the invoice numbers ) and if the invoice has more than 1 product it gets repeated. I know this is because I am not filtering the query but the thing is I do not really know how to achieve this. Anyone know how to do this?

```
I tried with LIMIT 1 but I get only 1 result ...
```

EDIT NOTE PLEASE

Some products has no invoice number because I sold those products to friends so the field ( invoice ) is empty, thats why I need to even filter this, that product sales with empty invoice in column do not get displayed

Comment: Are there any constraints on the table?

Comment: you mean restrictions? No no one, because we are in test mode I have set all privs to the mysql user

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Which columns do you want to appear in your result set?  Can you show us a sample desired output?

Comment: Do you only want to see unique invoice numbers? Does it matter if any products are reported back?

Comment: Exactly, to show unique invoice number only once per sale no matter how many products sold by under the same invoice it only gets displayed once and if there is no invoice ( is empty in database ) then it gets no displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
"SELECT * FROM `sales` WHERE `date` = '$today' GROUP BY `invoice`"
```

In any case, I think you should always have an invoice number, maybe a different kind, even when you sold them to friends. :)

If you don't want empty invoice numbers:

```
// Assuming by empty you mean NULL, please modify accordingly
"SELECT * FROM `sales` WHERE `date` = '$today' AND `invoice` IS NOT NULL GROUP BY invoice"
```

Comment: if the invoice field is empty it will not be displayed right?

Comment: It will still show up in the above result set, but only once, I'll update the answer

Comment: Just a small thing. How is the correct form is this query? It gives me error FROM `sales` WHERE `invoice` = .$show[invoice]."); // this show invoice is giving me error

Comment: For PHP variables, you can access it within double quotes, but not array values. See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165804/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-string-in-on-line-17/20165859#20165859